# Which parts of the project to commit in a team project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

This may be a stupid and easy question but I don't know. I'm working (with other people too) on java projects (java maven projects) with Eclipse and SVN.
When I commit my changes, do I just need to commit the `*.java` files I changed or the whole java *Maven* project ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is a good idea to ask your team for common rules or best practice. So if they want you to only change `*.java` files, you are better off to contribute only changes that respect this requirement.

In most SW-teams or companies, however, a project is not only made from *plain* source code. Many projects are composed of `.properties` files, *XML*-based configuration, e.g. Maven's project and module definitions found in `pom.xml` files, or even things like *SQL*-snippets that is shared for development purposes. From time to time, a developer needs to conduct changes to these non-`*.java` files. So it might get "blocking" if you would't share these adjustments with your team via a common repository, i.e. here: *git* or *svn*.

In essence, ask your team what they expect from you as a contributor OR let your team discuss and make a decision on how you want to organise the project and the code repository on a file level.

*Edit*: Beware of hidden directories with local configuration information, i.e. the IDE-environment such as properties of the local workspace. These are clearly developer specific things.

Hope it helps.

Comment: OK thanks. Of course if I'm changing/creating properties files/SQL files I need to commit them too.  But I think I should only commit files that I've changed and not the whole project/module. because if other people from my team are changing other files of the same project, I would erase these changes if I'm committing the whole project. Right ?